# Nothing Visible in Media manager & in Article Images & links

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, media-manager

In my joomla website, if i click on media manager, nothing is visible(i.e. everything loads except the images & folders), same thing happens in articles when i add the intro image or full article image.
[image: image for reference]

I have set the permission to the tmp folder and also to the images folder 777 .
Image added for reference.

Still nothing shows up.

Can anyone help???

Comment: Try removing the .htaccess file briefly from your root file via FTP.  If that fixes it, then you probably have a security setting too high (make sure you put it back).  I do not recommend leaving your folder at 777.  The system should work just fine at 0755.  If you use Firebug or Developer tools, does it show an error in the console?

Answer (score 1):

I checked in firebug and found that iframes were not opening , checked with domain provider, they denied the permission of the x-frame.

The issue was soled by changing the permission for the X_FRAME.

Answer (score 0):

change the X-frame option to SAMEORIGIN from deny in .htaccess

I did the same thing form my website too.

Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN